# should I use public method to access private variable inside a class?

Tags: javascript, oop, encapsulation

The pseudo-code is in JavaScript. I have the class `Animal` and the method `typeMatches` that uses private variable `_type` that holds the type of the animal:

```
function Animal()
{
    this._type = "dog";
}
Animal.prototype.getAnimalType = function()
{
    return this._type;
}
Animal.protytype.typeMatches = function(animalType)
{
    //option 1 - accessing private variable directly
    return this._type === animalType;
    //option 2 - accessing private through public method
    return this.getAnimalType() === animalType; //accessing private through public method
}
```

I've always used private variables directly from inside the class (option 1), however I was told recently that it's a bad practice and I should use public methods to get private variables whenever I have a chance to do so (option 2). But I question this advice on the grounds that the variable is private and I'm using it inside the class so I'm not breaking any conventions, while the direct access makes my code clearer to me. Am I wrong?

Comment: It's only necessary when there is some logic going on in the getter that is relevant inside the class as well, which is very rarely.

Comment: Agreed with Jeroen. Unless you have a relevant cause to use getters of a specific class inside that class, there really is no point.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel using the getter means that if logic gets added later you are already calling it. It's preserve the abstraction and is a simple OOP principle.

Comment: @ArtB: I made an answer instead.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel I made the comment while reviewing the question, my bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it when it's absolutely needed (and avoid it whenever possible).

The only task of a getter is to return the data, perhaps after a transformation to make it more easy to use.

For example the backing field

```
long _ticks = 500000000000L;
```

Can have a getter

```
public long GetTicks() 
{
    return _ticks;
}
```

It is indeed correct that in this case there is no difference between using the backing field and the getter. The problem with using getters however is that you are now making both your external *and* your internal representation of the data the same.

We can express very easily why this is a problem: what if we want to return our `_ticks` as a `string` to the outside world? Now we *have* to break internal functionality or otherwise we won't be able to change something as ordinary as a public interface.

Indeed: the very thing we are trying to accomplish with the encapsulation of our private fields is now broken because you would be trying to use external representation inside the internal functionality.

This code will now break other code inside our class that relied on it being passed a numeric type instead of a `string`.

```
public string GetTicks() 
{
    return _ticks.ToString();
}
```

There are very, very little situations where I would advocate the use of a getter inside the class itself (a calculated field like @Noel's `GetAge()` comes to mind) and if I do it's because it's the last feasible option. Keep your internal and external representation separated, it will save you headaches.

<sub>(I'm not very familiar with Javascript but I believe the code samples are clear enough. I realize Javascript cares less about exact types but this is merely an example: there are many different kinds of transformations possible.)</sub>

Comment: why not just use a private getter? This way you do not expose anything but you have the choice to make a calculated field later without changing all of your code.

Comment: It's a workaround but you'll have to ask yourself if it's actually worth it. How often do you consciously use a getter instead of the direct field because you functionally need it? Very little for me personally and I don't think I like the tradeoff of 10 private getters in case I need one someday. In the end I can always do a search-replace for `_ticks` and replace it with `GetPrivateTicks()`.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel, thanks a lot for taking pains to provide clear example demonstrating why using getters for private properties is a bad thing.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel good point. I agree especially for small projects.

Answer (score 1):

As @Jeroen Vannevel pointet out it is only "essential" if some logic is behind the getting/setting.

For example if you have two properties:
1) BirthYear:
2) Age

The easiest way would be to calculate the Age when setting the BirtYear. 
You could do 1 setter to set both properties and 2 getters for each property.

The reason why people recommended to you to always use getters/setters is that you would always have the **same structure** in your code and you would **never break any functionality** by changing a getter/setter. Additionally **you don't have to differentiate between properties and functions while accessing them** (you only got functions)

I use em' pretty much always. It is more consistent.